# Imacros script won't write on text field

Tags: javascript, imacros

I'm trying to prank one of my close friends so i'm working on a imacros script but I'm having a hard time trying to get it to write on a text field. I'm guessing its because its a div is there any way around this?

Imarcros script

```
VERSION BUILD=8881205 RECORDER=FX
TAG POS=2 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:Add<SP>a<SP>comment...
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:Pf&&TXT:
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:z13pzjwrelzadpbrv04cehphklu1tjxzemc0k.editor
```

The html

```
<div id="z13pzjwrelzadpbrv04cehphklu1tjxzemc0k.editor" jsname="L9AdLc" class="cp"><div class="Pf"><div role="textbox" g_editable="true" class="df b-K b-K-Xb URaP8 editable" id=":37.f" contenteditable="true"></div></div></div>

<div class="Pf"><div role="textbox" g_editable="true" class="df b-K b-K-Xb URaP8 editable" id=":37.f" contenteditable="true"></div></div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to include a sample of the HTML you're trying to have it affect. Thanks for improving the question for future searchers!

Comment: Thank you, the HTML has been added.